# Passing arguments to UIcontrol callback function

Tags: matlab, arguments, uicontrol

I am making an app to track my finances and I am confused as how to pass a string to a callback function in a uicontrol pushbutton object.

For instance:

```
classdef moneyapp < handle
methods (Access = public)
        function app = moneyApp
            % uicontrol object example
            app.NewSymbolGLMC = uicontrol(app.FigureGLMC,...   
                'Style','pushbutton','Position',[300 60 200 20],...
                'String','New Stock',...
                'Callback', {@app.newStock,'Account Name'});
        end
        function newStock(src,eventData,account)
            % Do something with the string, 'Account Name'
        end
    end
end
```

end

I am confused as to how to get the string, 'Account Name', to the newStock function. This is an essential part to my code and I just think my syntax is not correct; more examples of the code can be provided if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since `newStock` is a method of your class, the first input *must* be the object itself. Because of this you need four input arguments in your function definition:
the instance, the source and event data (the default inputs), and the account name.

```
function newStock(obj, src, eventData, account)
```

As a side note, the capitalization of your constructor (`moneyApp`) must match the capitalization of the class (`moneyapp`) to be treated as a constructor.